# Worklight 6.1- How to import self sign certificate in MAC machine same as windows

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using `worklight 6.1` version and `MAC 10.8`. I have build the project which uses adapter and it require self sign certificate. On windows I know how to do that and it works fine for me but when I am trying the same worklight setup on MAC machine. I am not able to do that. I have tried to import certificate and remove the default path in worklight.properties file as i have done the same thing in windows but it din't worked for me.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/rstep1.html

```
#SSL certificate keystore location.
#ssl.keystore.path=conf/default.keystore
#SSL certificate keystore type (jks or PKCS12)
#ssl.keystore.type=jks
#SSL certificate keystore password.
#ssl.keystore.password=worklight
```

Please help me if there is any docs regarding that.

Answer (score 3):

The following documentation shows instructions for "Configuring SSL between Worklight adapters and back-end servers by using self-signed certificates":

https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html

In regards to importing the certificate into the default keystore you can do something similar to the following as described in the above documentation:

```
keytool -import -alias backend -file backend.crt -storetype JKS -keystore default.keystore
```

Please let me know if you have any trouble following these instructions. I have completed these steps on a MAC machine myself and was successful.

Comment: What is the default password when we import in MAC....in windows i know it is  'changeit'.

Comment: it got successfully imported in default.keystore, i restarted the server , even after doing this it is giving peer not authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use keystore explorer (http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/) , this is a great GUI tool to work with keystores and certificates. as for ssl.keystore.path you can specify both relative and absolute path to your keystore file

Comment: Yes , I have this tool on my MAC machine, but let me know how to import certificate to the default keystore for worklight so that i can start with my adapter. In this i already added my certificate but no luck.